# Name and complexity of a problem concerning metrics

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, graph-isomorphism

Do you know the name of the following problem and can you give a reference for its complexity (especially the relation to $\mathsf{GraphIsomorphism}$ and/or other isomorphism/homomorphism problems)?

> Given two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2: V^2 \to \mathbb{N}$. Does there exist a  permutation $\pi$ on $V$ such that $d': V^2\to \mathbb{N}$ with 
>   $$d'(u,v)=\min \{d_1(u,v),d_2(\pi(u),\pi(v))\}$$
>   is a metric?

Motivation: Think of two fishing nets. If you try to fasten every knot of one net to every knot of the other net, the maximal distance between two knots is determined by the length of the shorter thread in the two nets.